# How to get the code and jwt from SUUNTO API OAuth2?

Tags: python

When I do this:

curl -v https://cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com/oauth/token --user : -d grant_type=authorization_code -d redirect_uri= -d code=<authorization code from step 4.4>

It works but I can not make it to work with the script below:

```
import requests

header={
"Authorization":"Basic Base64{user:pwd}"
}
def jwtRequest():
    url = f'https://cloudapi-oauth.suunto.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=&code='
    req = requests.post(url,header)
    return req
```

Step 4 ( https://apizone.suunto.com/how-to-start )
Thank you in advance,

PS. For security reasons I left out client_id and code.

Comment: It would be much easier for someone to help if you could edit your question to include a complete, minimal working code snippet (minus the client_id and code), usually starting with `import`.  Also, be sure to include the complete error output you get, if any (masking sensitive details if necessary).

Comment: Already edited it. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here

```
requests.post(url,header)
```

had to be:

```
requests.post(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pswd'))
```

This already converts the user and pwd into Base64 and passes in the right way on the requests.